# Installing PhantomJS on Mac

Tags: installation, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to install PhantomJS on my Mac (Yosemite).

I did the following:

```
npm install phantomjs
```

Then I did:

```
npm install phantomjs-prebuilt
```

Both of which appear in my node_modules. But when I try to run `phantomjs --version`I get

```
   -bash: phantomjs: command not found
```

Also tried installing the binary from the downloads website, but nothing. What am I missing? End goal is to use casperjs but currently casper is asking

```
Fatal: [Errno 2] No such file or directory; did you install phantomjs?
```

I thought I did....?

Answer (score 71):

If you are using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/), you can type:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
brew cask install phantomjs
```

Comment: It was migrated from homebrew/core to homebrew/cask.
You can access it again by running:
  brew tap homebrew/cask
And then you can install it by running:
  brew cask install phantomjs

Comment: It reminded me to use `brew install --cask phantomjs`.

Answer (score 41):

1. Download phantomjs latest version (ex: phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip) from   http://phantomjs.org/download.html
2. Extract it to some path(ex: ~/Desktop/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx)
3. Run this command on terminal - 
   sudo ln -n ~/Desktop/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/
4. Launch phantomjs from the terminal by command: phantomjs
5. Check phantomjs version by command: phantomjs -v
6. Check the phantomjs path by command: which phantomjs

Comment: You've saved me.

Answer (score 26):

The accepted answer is outdated. On Mac, using Homebrew, type:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
brew cask install phantomjs
```

The first step may not be necessary for some MacOS versions.

For newer versions of cask (2021 and later), use

```
brew install --cask phantomjs
```

Comment: First it asks for > brew tap homebrew/cask > then your answer. At least for High Sierra and Mojave.

Comment: Here updated version of cask.  
brew install --cask phantomjs

Answer (score 18):

You need to add phantomjs binary to your PATH. You can do this either by modifying the environment variable or by symlinking the binary to for example `/usr/local/bin`

For example, if you want to symlink the binary:

```
cd $HOME
curl -O https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip
ln -s $HOME/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

or if you want to modify the PATH environment variable:

```
cd $HOME
curl -O https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip
```

and add this line to this file: `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin:$PATH
```

and then run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: why don't they make a proper installer?

Comment: Same for windows as well. PITA for newcomers

Comment: I was not able to unzip `phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip`. @Godraude

Comment: Has anyone managed to download and unzip the latest macosx phantomjs package?

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you be installing `phantomjs` globally?

`npm install -g phantomjs`

Since you are installing it locally, the command -

`phantomjs -v`

would not work everywhere.

You can check the difference between local install and global install here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of digging I found that on on High-Sierra old versions of phantomjs (<2.0) [would not work](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14558).

Also, the zip file via the [phantomjs download page](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) is a faulty one.

If you need a new phantom, just go to [this](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/) page and download phantomjs 2.1.1 (or later).

Answer (score -1):

for Mac BigSur

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
brew install --cask phantomjs
```