# PhantomJS attempting to install as if OS is Linux/arm64 when I am using Mac Big Sur?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, npm, phantomjs

I am receiving the below error message when running npm install on a project: 
#10 35.10 PhantomJS not found on PATH 
#10 35.10 Unexpected platform or architecture: linux/arm64 
#10 35.10 It seems there is no binary available for your platform/architecture 
#10 35.10 Try to install PhantomJS globally 
[screenshot of terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwGvc.png)

The problem is, I am not using a Linux OS, I am using Mac BigSur.

I have tried installing PhantomJS globally using HomeBrew. 
I also tried setting a path according to this article [Installing PhantomJS on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36993962/installing-phantomjs-on-mac) 
Like this:

"and add this line to this file: ~/.bash_profile:

export PATH=$HOME/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx/bin:$PATH"

I also tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json, then reinstalling.

[Here is a screenshot of my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Sfg.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!